# Django equivalent of Rails' content_for helper

Tags: django, django-templates

In my Django project I have script tags both in the base templates, templates that extend the base template, and partials that are included in various templates. I want to collect all these script tags and output them in order at the bottom of the page.

One proposed solution is to create a block in the main template, and then override it in extended templates, but this doesn't work for include files, which have no access to blocks.

Rails solves this with a content_for helper, which concatenates the html it contains and makes it available to all templates. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html#method-i-content_for

Is there an equivalent for Django?

Answer (score 2):

There's no equivalent in Django for content_for.

However, you might want to look at [django-sekizai](https://github.com/ojii/django-sekizai). It will aggregate blocks of CSS and JavaScript into one block in your base template. When used in conjunction with [django-compressor](http://django_compressor.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html), the resulting `<script>` or `<link>` tags can be compressed into one `<link>` or `<script>` tag to reduce Http requests.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. The sekizai project seems to address the precise use case from my question.